# Existence of measure given the margin is a step function

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, calculus-of-variations

Suppose  $Q:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is given by a nondecreasing step function

$$Q(x)=A,  if \phantom{0}0\leq x < x^*$$

$$\phantom{0000} = B, if\phantom{0}   x^*\leq x\leq 1 $$

s.t. $$A,B\in[0,1]  \phantom{0}and \phantom{0} A\leq B$$

where $x^*\in(0,1)$ is given.

Suppose $F:[0,1]\to R_+$ is a  c.d.f. What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $(A,B,x^*,F)$ such that there exists $q:[0,1]^2\to [0,1]$ satisfies

$$\int_{[0,1]}q(x,y)dF(y)=Q(x)$$

$$\int_{[0,1]}q(x,y)dF(x)=Q(y)$$

?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't Q be defined as $[0,1] \mapsto \{A,B\}$? Also, shouldn't F be defined as $[0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$? That might be causing you issues right there. Also, please tell us what you've tried.

Comment: hi, thanks for these points. $F$ is defined as $[0,1]\to [0,1]$. For Q, A,B are given parameters, could we make it in the definition? I think I could find some step function q which divide $[0,1]^2$ into 4 rectangles. Is it possible to show that all the solutions  are of this linear form?